# How to add text functionality to html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am making a whiteboard based on the html5 canvas and have add various functions like upload pdf, pencil, undo, redo and so on. Can someone help me with the the text tool. Basically after selecting the text tool on clicking on the canvas a text box should appear there to which we can input the text and the text appears on the canvas. Once the text is submitted we should be able to edit it and also draw on top of it. Can someone please help me with this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Register a `mousedown` event on the `<canvas>` and make use of `fillText` to render the text. You may also register a `keydown` event to capture key input.